# Making a roulete style Poly Wheel in Java

Tags: java, swing, math, polygons

I am working on a project and I have come to a stand still . Currently, I am creating a roulette style wheel that will be rotating, the problem I have come to is creating a n' amount of polygons for the wheel. I would like in the end to be able to set the n' number and use a for loops to create the polygons' points. I tried to use the the parametric equation of that certain circle, but the y value were incorrect being that pixels are dealt with differently. The rotation is working correctly with the Rotateicon class. So plain question, How do I create n' number of polygons from a given center, begging x,y to end up with a wheel?

**The Code**

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;




public class Wheel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel label;
    private Icon icon;
    private Icon rotated;
    private int degrees;
    private static Point center;

    public Wheel(Image image)
    {   
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        center = new Point(250/2, 250/2);

        icon = new ImageIcon( image );
        label = new JLabel(icon);
        label.setPreferredSize( label.getPreferredSize() );
        add( label );
        setDegrees( 0 );
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        double radians = Math.toRadians( degrees );
        rotated = new RotatedIcon(icon, degrees);
        label.setIcon(rotated);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Image bi = RotatableImage.getImage(250);
                final Wheel r = new Wheel(bi);

                    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 0);
                    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                        {
                            int value = slider.getValue();
                            r.setDegrees( value );
                        }
                    });

                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new JScrollPane(r));
                f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    static class RotatableImage
    {
        private static final Random r = new Random();

        static public Image getImage(int size)
        {
            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setPaint(Color.getHSBColor(r.nextFloat(), 1, 1));
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10.0f));

            Polygon flag = new Polygon();
            flag.addPoint(125, 125);
            flag.addPoint(205, 250/2);
            flag.addPoint(205, 250/2+10);



            g2d.draw(flag);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.fillOval(120, 120, 10, 10);

            g2d.dispose();
            return bi;
        }


    }


}
```

If needed the rotation icon is: 
http://pastebin.com/Sbb38ifU

What I am getting:

[image]

What I am trying to end up with:

[image]

Comment: It would likely help if you could post images of what you want to get and what you're getting instead.

Comment: Like the wheel of fortune wheel: http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2011/202/2/8/blank_wheel_template_by_larry4009-d416r88.png

Comment: I don't see any oval's on that image so I'm left wondering what `g2d.fillOval()` was meant to do.

Comment: It is just the center point. This is what it looks like currently. http://s24.postimg.org/n2detbgph/Screen_Shot_2015_04_19_at_10_26_43_AM.png

Comment: I would try to keep it simple, such as by using Arc2D with an arc-type of Arc2D.PIE to draw my pie sections onto a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use Arc2D to draw your pie slices. The bounding rectangle for this Shape is the rectangle that would enclose the entire circle that this Arc slice is cut from. You could then construct your multi-colored pie slices in a for loop, and draw the slices onto a BufferedImage which is then displayed in a JPanel's paintComponent method. This image can be rotated by using an AffineTransform on the Graphics2D object that draws it, but you must be careful since you don't want to transform the Graphics object given to you by the JVM as the paintComponent method's parameter. For that reason, you'll want to make a copy Graphics2D object and then transform it:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(); // create a copy to rotate
  if (image != null) {
     if (af != null) {
        g2.transform(af);
     }
     g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
  }
  g2.dispose(); // OK to do this as we created this object
}
```

You should never dispose of a Graphics object given to you by the JVM, but since our g2 object is a copy, it's OK and actually desired to dispose of it so we don't run out of resources. For instance:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FooArcs extends JPanel {
   public static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private PiePanel piePanel;
   private JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 260, 0);

   public FooArcs(int imageWidth, int divisions) {
      slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
      slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
      slider.setPaintLabels(true);
      slider.setPaintTicks(true);

      piePanel = new PiePanel(imageWidth, divisions);

      slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
      add(piePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(slider, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
         int value = slider.getValue();
         piePanel.rotate(value);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      int imageWidth = PREF_W;
      int divisions = 24;
      FooArcs mainPanel = new FooArcs(imageWidth, divisions);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FooArcs");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PiePanel extends JPanel {
   private BufferedImage image;
   private Random random = new Random();
   private AffineTransform af;
   private int imageWidth;

   public PiePanel(int imageWidth, int divisions) {
      this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
      image = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageWidth, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      for (int i = 0; i < divisions; i++) {
         drawPie(g2, i, imageWidth, divisions);
      }
      g2.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(); // create a copy to rotate
      if (image != null) {
         if (af != null) {
            g2.transform(af);
         }
         g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
      }
      g2.dispose(); // OK to do this as we created this object
   }

   private void drawPie(Graphics2D g2, int i, int imageWidth2, int divisions) {
      Color c = getRandomColor();
      double x = 1.0;
      double y = x;
      double w = imageWidth2 - 2;
      double h = w;
      double start = i * 360.0 / divisions; // starting angle
      double extent = 360.0 / divisions; // size of slice in degrees
      int type = Arc2D.PIE;
      Arc2D arc = new Arc2D.Double(x, y, w, h, start, extent, type);

      g2.setColor(c);
      g2.fill(arc);
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.draw(arc);
   }

   private Color getRandomColor() {
      Integer a = random.nextInt(128) + 128;
      Integer b = random.nextInt(128) + (random.nextBoolean() ? 128 : 0);
      Integer c = random.nextInt(128);
      List<Integer> colors = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {a, b, c});
      Collections.shuffle(colors);
      Color color = new Color(colors.get(0), colors.get(1), colors.get(2));

      return color;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(imageWidth, imageWidth);
   }

   public void rotate(int degrees) {
      double theta = Math.toRadians(degrees);
      double anchorx = imageWidth / 2.0;
      double anchory = anchorx;
      af = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta, anchorx, anchory);
      repaint();
   }
}
```

This displays as:

[image]

Comment: Edit: oops -- I should have used 360, not 260 for my JSlider max!

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a right angle triangle.  What you are trying to make is closer to a series of rotated isosceles triangles.

Easy way to get an isosceles is stick two right angle triangles together:

```
        flag.addPoint(125, 125);
//        flag.addPoint(205, 250/2);
        flag.addPoint(205, 250/2+10);
        flag.addPoint(205, 250/2-10);
```

This will need some more tweaking.  The circumference should be a circle not a polygon. Still need to make a series of these and there's now a hole to fill since you're trying to fill the triangle using line thickness.  But now at least the angles are correct.

[image]